# Spring Security and Thymeleaf with updated authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

During one session I change user role with:

```
Authentication newAuth = new  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(newUser.geteMail(), newUser.getPassword(), AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(newUser.getUserRole().name()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
        RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", newAuth, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_SESSION);
```

It changes in java code.
I'm trying to recieve user role in html using `<span sec:authentication="principal.authorities"></span>` , but get the following error after the code above:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error retrieving value for property "principal.authorities" of authentication object of class org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken (index:115)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
```

I use Spring MVC 5 and thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4. Without changing role during the session tags of extras work. How can the authentication be updated also in html?

### Edit

I've tried to use thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5 and got an alert with 'Bad credentials' when the page reloads after authentication update. In trace there are no errors now, but it shows the previous role. Also updated my code like this:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken newAuth = new  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(newUser.geteMail(), newUser.getPassword(), AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(newUser.getUserRole().name()));
Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(newAuth);

SecurityContext sc = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
sc.setAuthentication(auth);
HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, sc);
```

Comment: Is that the whole trace?  Also, why not use `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5`?

Comment: @vphilipnyc No, there is not the whole trace, I've updated the question with version 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<span sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" sec:authentication="principal.authorities">
```

Comment: <span sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" sec:authentication="principal.authorities">

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!